# <magento_instance>/graphql not working on windows but works on linux machine

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.3.0, graphql, mariadb

Officially Magento2.3 supports only these operating systems

> Linux distributions, such as RedHat Enterprise Linux (RHEL), CentOS,
>   Ubuntu, Debian, and similar.

**This is my configuration**

- Installed Magento2.3.0 with sample data On
- Windows 10
- Apache2.4
- PHP Version 7.2.12 (PHP compiled with Xampp)
- Database Server version: 10.1.22-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary
  distribution

My question is about How to make this work on windows (XAMPP)?

http://magento23.me/graphql
`This URL doesn't load to me in windows`

[image]

Comment: yes I got same error and also, checked it's in developer mode but still graphql url is not working and getting error like site can't be reached.

Comment: is it really with http?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/146185)

Comment: Found any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

`graphql` works only in `developer` mode so make sure that your Magento is on `developer` mode.

[Magento DevDocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/graphql/)

> You can access the GraphQL introspection feature only if your Magento
>   instance is in developer mode.

Comment: It is in developer mode I have tested this in 3 different windows instance